# Вызов нестатичного метода из другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы

Я делаю игру, и мне понадобилось вызвать метод из другого файла.Да вот не получается.Статичным ничего делать нельзя.
File1

```
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {
     public void Shot(){
             Blaster.PewPew();
     }
}
```

File2

```
public class Blaster : MonoBehaviour {
     public void PewPew(){
          // сделать что-нибудь
     }
}
```

Comment: P.S.Да, вопрос однозначно тупой, а ответ гениально прост.Но я пытался сделать все сам, так и не получилось.

Comment: Blaster b=new Blaster(); b.PewPew();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз у вас есть класс `Shoot`, которому нужен бластер, то вам нужно дать этому классу *экземпляр* бластера. Соответственно бластер должен приходить либо в конструкторе (ну или в крайнем случае через публичное свойство), либо как аргумент метода.

Получится либо так:

```
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {
     Blaster blaster;
     public void Shot(){
             blaster.PewPew();
     }
     // тут другой код
}
```

либо так:

```
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {
     Blaster blaster = new Blaster();
     public void Shot(){
             blaster.PewPew();
     }
}
```

либо так:

```
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {
     public void Shot(Blaster blaster){
             blaster.PewPew();
     }
}
```

Comment: Только в первом случае его ещё кто-то создать должен.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, это случай, когда он должен приходить в конструкторе.

Comment: Я же говорил,ответ гениально прост...Но вариант `Blaster b = new Blaster();` мне будет удобнее.

Comment: @JetFly: Или так, да. Добавил этот вариант явно.